# How to find whether a url is of ecommerce or non ecommerce website, programatically?

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, mahout

In a project there is a module takes a URL and determines whether it is of "Ecommerce" or "NON-Ecommerce" website.

I have tried following approaches:

1. Using Apache mahout, Classification : URL  ---> Take html dump ---> pre process the html dump by 
   a) removing all html tags

   b) removing stop words(a.k.a common words) like CDATA, href, value, and, of , between etc.

   c) training model and then testing it.

Following params i have used for training

> bin/mahout trainclassifier \   -i training-data \   -o bayes-model \  > -type bayes -ng 1

Testing:

```
/bin/mahout testclassifier \
  -d test-data \
  -m bayes-model \
  -type bayes -source hdfs -ng 1 -method sequential
```

Accuracy i am getting as 73% and with cbayes algorithm getting 52%.

I am thinking to improve pre processing stage by extracting info which are found in ecommerce website like "Checkout button","pay pal link", "Prices/ dollar symbol", text like "Cash on delivery", "30 day gurantee" etc.

Any suggestions on how to extract this info or any other ways to predict a site as Ecommerce or Non-Ecommerce?

Comment: Please format your question the next time a bit more carefully. And btw 70% accuracy is quite good for the start.

Answer (score 1):

I am very astonished that you get such a good accuracy with just plain html extraction and a bayes classifier.

But you seem to be on the right track with the features like a checkout button and prices.

Here is a paper I found yesterday while reading about Yandex:

["To find out or to buy? Product review vs. Web shop classifier"](http://www.dialog-21.ru/dialog2011/materials/pdf/17.pdf)

It is about how to distinct these two sites and some techniques they used. They also used SVM instead of naive bayes.

Comment: Thanks thomas. Paper is targeting the similar use case as ours.